# MySQL dividing current row with current row + 1

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL query. I have two tables, table currency and table currency_detail. Table currency contains currency code, such as USD, EUR, IDR, etc. Table currency_detail contains date and rate. After joining tables to get all rates USD in 1 year, I have data which look like this :

```
Date       | Rate
-------------------
2015-10-20 | 14463
2015-10-19 | 14452
2015-10-18 | 14442
2015-10-15 | 14371
2015-10-14 | 14322
2015-10-10 | 14306
2015-10-08 | 14322
```

I need to count every current row with current row + 1. Is it possible to get results that look like this ?

```
Date       | Rate  | PX
------------------------------
2015-10-20 | 14463 | 0.000761     -> LN(14463/14452)
2015-10-19 | 14452 | 0.000692     -> LN(14452/14442)
2015-10-18 | 14442 | 0.004928     -> LN(14442/14371)
2015-10-15 | 14371 | 0.003415     -> LN(14371/14322)
2015-10-14 | 14322 | 0.001118     -> LN(14322/14306)
2015-10-10 | 14306 | -0.00112     -> LN(14306/14322)
2015-10-08 | 14322 | 0            -> 0 (because no data after this row)
```

I have tried many ways, but still cant find the solutions. Anyone can help with the query ? Thanks before..

Comment: What are the many ways you've tried. Please show what you've done.

Comment: is there any primary key for `currency_detail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL you would simply use `LAG` to read the value from the previous record. In MySQL you need a workaround. The easiest way might be to select all rows twice and number them on-the-fly; then you can join by row number:

```
select
  this.rdate, this.rate,
  ln(this.rate / prev.rate) as px
from
(
  select @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 as rownum, rates.* 
  from rates
  cross join (select @rownum1 := 0) init
  order by rdate
) this
left join
(
  select @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 as rownum, rates.* 
  from rates
  cross join (select @rownum2 := 0) init
  order by rdate
) prev on prev.rownum = this.rownum - 1
order by this.rdate desc;
```

I had to use different rownum variable names in the two subqueries, by the way, as MySQL got confused otherwise. I consider this a flaw, but I must admit MySQL's variables-in-SQL thing is still kind of alien to me :-)

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/341c4/7